# How can I pop to any view controller as I wish?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

view controller A B C D
A -> B -> C-> D
popViewController only form D to C
popViewTopController only form D to A;
Any way can I pop to any view as I wish if I have 10 view controllers?

Thanks for everyone.  will the popViewController pop to a new view Controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pop any view you want to change `objectAtIndex`:1,2,3..etc
it will pop to first,second etc... from the any views.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: Select by class**

To tell the `navigationController` to pop to a specific class, you can do as follows:

```
NSArray *allViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *aViewController in allViewControllers) 
{
  if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[B class]]) 
  {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Take into account that you should only use this, if you are not pushing instances of the same class several times.

**Option 2: Select by level**

If you want to pop to a specific level, you can just select it by index at `self.navigationController.viewControllers` since it correspond to the levels. The first pushed UIViewController will be at index 0, the second at index 1 and so on:

```
NSArray *allViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
UIViewController *aViewController = [allViewControllers objectAtIndex:level];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you are looking for [(reference)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:)

In Obj-c

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You should pass in the view controller that you want pop to

Answer (score 0):

Use the following UINavigationController method to go to any view controller on the current stack.

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                        animated:(BOOL)animated
```

For example, if you are in a UIViewController and you want to pop back to the third one in the stack:

```
UINavigationController * nc = self.navigationController;
UIViewController * popToVC = [nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
[nc popToViewController:popToVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SecondViewController *sec = [SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController popViewController:Sec animated:YES];
```